# Accessing $_POST array on redirect after .ajaxForm()

Tags: jquery, html, forms, post, ajaxform

I have a form that submits files and when I click 'submit' button I have a jquery script running and showing the upload progress in percentage. After the upload percentage is 100% I want the page to continue uploading POST form as usual (to redirect to the page that is spesified in action='') but when I redirect the page using jquery I can no longer get the

```
$_POST['']
```

array and all the variables.

*My question is*: how can I access all the $_POST variables that have been just uploaded as in usual POST upload without .ajaxForm?

So without .ajaxForm I get redirected right away after the file has been uploaded and I can access the $_POST array and the $_POST['Submit'] is true and I want to keep this same way but just to add the progress upload bar because the form is made to upload videos(big files) and I want to let user know where the video upload progress is now. So I want on success to redirect to action page and be able to access all the $_POST variables there.

Help me, please!!!

JQUERY and HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
 <style>
 .progress { position:relative; width:400px; border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 1px; border-radius: 3px; }
 .bar { background-color: #B4F5B4; width:0%; height:20px; border-radius: 3px; }
 .percent { position:absolute; display:inline-block; top:3px; left:48%; }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="videator-b.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="theFile"><br>
    <input type="submit" name='Submit' value="Upload File to Server">
</form>

<div class="progress">
    <div class="bar"></div >
    <div class="percent">0%</div >
</div>

<div id="status"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {
var bar = $('.bar');
var percent = $('.percent');
var status = $('#status');
$('form').ajaxForm({ 
beforeSend: function() {
    status.empty();
    var percentVal = '0%';
    bar.width(percentVal)
    percent.html(percentVal);
},
uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
    var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
    bar.width(percentVal)
    percent.html(percentVal);
},
complete: function(xhr) { 
    status.html('Wait please, redirecting...');
window.location.replace("//this is where I want to redirect to videator-b.php but be able to access $_POST array the is beinguploaded');
}
}); 
})();       
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php require_once ('esse.php');
   if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){ 
    $fileName = trim($_FILES['theFile']['name']);
    $fileTempName = $_FILES['theFile']['tmp_name'];
    $ext = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);  
    $size = $_FILES['theFile']['size'];  
   }              
 ?>
```

Comment: you can write all the upload code on the action page the page will not redirect when you use ajaxForm and all the variable are accessible on the action page i.e videator-b.php

Comment: but I NEED to go to another page after gorm is submit and access all the variables there.  And I DO write all the upload code (php code) in the videator-b.php and i know the page doesnot redirect when i use ajaxForm. And my question is how to redirect to another page an access post variables!

Comment: You should write the files to disk (on the server)... And place the other infos in database. But you can also use `$_SESSION` variables (in `videator-b.php`) to pass it to the other page, if this is where you want to do it. Have a look here : http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: you should try window.location.redirect = "where_to_redirect.php" instead of window.location.replace in the ajax request